# pycharm - how to import directory as a module, keeping directory name as part of the namespace

Tags: python

I have on my local machine following structure

```
all_code_root\
 - utils\
 -- some_specific_util.py
 - project1\
 -- app1.py
 - project2\
 -- app2.py
```

(utils and each project hosted in own git repository if that matters)
I'd like to set pycharm to work on a project1, while being able to recognize utils as a module, i.e. to be able to write in app1.py

```
from utils import some_specific_util
```

I've tried several options (marking the utils dir a source root, opening and attaching it as my project dependency etc), but I always end up only able to do this in app1

```
import some_specific_util  # referring directly to the file works
#from utils import some_specific_util # this does NOT work, 'utils' is not recognized as a module name to import from
```

Is using utils.some_specific_util actually possible in pycharm? I see only workaround/hack to create artificial pycharm 'project' on all_code_root level, or create unneeded subdir for utils) (Also tried adding __ init __.py or using File - Invalidate caches from menu; my pycharm version is 2022.2.2)

Answer (score 0):

If both python file and directory in same folder then this should be sufficient.
import utils

It will import all the Python files in the utils directory.

Comment: unfortunately they are not - it's all_code_root\utils\some_specific_util.py and all_code_root\project1\app1.py

Comment: Add this statement and import modules. sys.path.append(path_to_utils)